# How to do multiple nested IF statements in Terraform?

Tags: if-statement, terraform, terraform0.12+

It's possible to have ternary `if` statements in Terraform as such:

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "foo" {
  name = "bar"
  policy = (
    var.ENVIRONMENT == "green" ?
    data.aws_iam_policy_document.green.json : data.aws_iam_policy_document.red.json)
}
```

But is it possible to have multiple `if` statements that would be equivalent to this?

```
if var.ENVIRONMENT == "green"
then
  data.aws_iam_policy_document.green.json
else
  if var.ENVIRONMENT == "red"
    data.aws_iam_policy_document.red.json
  else
    if var.ENVIRONMENT == "blue"
      data.aws_iam_policy_document.blue.json
```

Comment: You can nest them: `condition ? (condition ? yes : no) : (condition ? yes : no)`

Answer (score 1):

```
policy = var.ENVIRONMENT == "green" ? data.aws_iam_policy_document.green.json : (var.ENVIRONMENT == "red" ? data.aws_iam_policy_document.red.json : data.aws_iam_policy_document.blue.json)
```

The syntax is:

```
policy = condition_1 ? yes_1 : (condition_2 ? yes_2 : yes_3)
```

The translation in Bash is:

```bash
if [[ condition_1 == "true" ]]
then
 value = yes_1
elif [[ condition_2 == "true" ]]
then
 value = yes_2
else
 value = yes_3
fi
```

In both Terraform and Bash, the final `else` statement assumes that `condition_3` is true.

Answer (score 0):

As TF doesn't support switches, conditions work. But too much nesting can get messy to read if you start doing it throughout. Can just make 3 resource blocks and do a single condition as its cleaner to read. Can also use modules to hide this repetition if you want to go further.

https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/conditionals

However, real question is what are you trying to achieve with this? If you are doing for different envs (e.g. dev, stage & prod) why not create separate .tfvar files and when you run terraform just point to the var file which would be cleaner and better practice.

`terraform apply -var-file="dev.tfvars"`

https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/values/variables#variable-definitions-tfvars-files